# Is killing a homosexual a sin (haram)?

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality

I was sure that any kind of killing in Islam is punished, but a friend of mine, that has a very strong belief, had heard and even agreed that "killing a homosexual is not a sin".
That sounds very ignorant to me, and I'm sure other people who know better can illuminate me.

Is killing a homosexual a sin (haram)?

Comment: The narrations about killing those who commit sodomy are all unreliable and haven't proven to be true.  The Prophet himself never killed nor had any homosexuals killed.

Comment: al-Tirmidhi (1456), Abu Dawood (4462)and Ibn Maajah (2561) narrated that Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever you find doing the action of the people of Loot, execute the one who does it and the one to whom it is done.”. Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

Answer (score 6):

The prohibition of taking an innocent life is a general ruling. If someone thinks there is an exception to it, the burden of proof is on them. Even for *hudud* punishments (and there is a difference of opinion on when *hadd* comes into play in the situation of homosexuality and to what extent), they are only carried out after due legal process and only on the authority of a legitimate ruler, never citizen-to-citizen.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the person is, whether he is gay, disabled, or whatever, it is still a sin to kill. It's a different fact if you kill someone due to defending yourself, but if you were to do that, you should just have faith in God

Answer (score 0):

Killing without proper trial is sin, We need witnesses or confession. **Execution of sodomite and catamite was ordered by prophet**. This is a kind of hadd punishment

> al-Tirmidhi (1456), Abu Dawood (4462)and Ibn Maajah (2561) narrated that Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever you find doing the action of the people of Loot, execute the one who does it and the one to whom it is done.”. Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.